# Generic longer function for types implementing len() function in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, borrow-checker

What I'm attempting to do is creating generic function that compares two instances of something that has length.

My code:

```
fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    let vec2 = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4);
    println!("Longest vector is: {:?}", longer_vec_gen(&vec1, &vec2));
    println!("Longest iterator is {:?}", longer_exact_size_iterator(&vec1.iter(), &vec2.iter()))
}

fn longer_vec_gen<'a, T>(x: &'a Vec<T>, y: &'a Vec<T>) -> &'a Vec<T> {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}

fn longer_exact_size_iterator<'a, T: ExactSizeIterator>(x: &'a T, y: &'a T) -> &'a T {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

Both of those functions works however the first one works only for *Vec* so I wanted to make step forward and do it for anything that has length. The second one kinda achieves this, but right now I'm forced to use *.iter()* on parameters while calling this function which I would love to avoid.

Another problem is that i can't pass *String* or *string literals* to this function.

What I would love to achieve is creating function *longer* that would take any two elements that has implemented function *.len()* so this code would run without errors:

```
fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    let vec2 = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4);
    println!("Longer vector is: {:?}", longer(&vec1, &vec2));

    let string1 = String::from("abcd");
    let string2 = String::from("xyz");
    println!("Longest string is : {:?}", longer(&string1, &string2))
}

fn longer(...) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but right now I'm forced to use `.iter()` on parameters while calling this function which I would love to avoid

You can solve that particular issue by bounding on `IntoIterator`.  This is a bit tricky since you want to return a reference that was passed in to the function, but `IntoIterator` consumes its receiver.  You can make this work by requiring that the type be `IntoIterator + Copy`.  Since `Copy` is satisfied by shared references, this function would work for references to most (if not all) standard container types:

```
fn longer_exact_size_iterator<T, U>(x: T, y: T) -> T
where T: IntoIterator<IntoIter=U> + Copy,
    U: ExactSizeIterator,
{
    if x.into_iter().len() > y.into_iter().len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

Now you can do `longer_exact_size_iterator(&vec1, &vec2)`.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a826c5a1a0b5366bff75457a7334ed4d))

If you want a variant that works for anything with a `.len()` but that may not have exact-size iterators then you'll have to write your own trait and implement it on the types you want to handle; it won't be automatic.  For example:

```
pub trait HasLength {
    fn len(self) -> usize;
}

impl<T> HasLength for &Vec<T> {
    fn len(self) -> usize {
        Vec::len(self)
    }
}

impl<T> HasLength for &[T] {
    fn len(self) -> usize {
        <[T]>::len(self)
    }
}

// And so on...

fn longer<T: HasLength + Copy>(x: T, y: T) -> T {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=660ab102db815704914a6173678bce8f))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Bounding to IntoIterator looks like something I was looking for.

Comment: With your suggestions I tried to do something like this:
https://pastebin.pl/view/67091398


but getting  **Conflicting implementations of trait `HasLength` for type `&std::string::String`** while String doesn't satisfy traits from where clause. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Miokloń I don't think what you're trying to do here is possible without specialization, which isn't stable yet.